# Importing project gave Unable to resolve target 'android-7'

Tags: android, eclipse, api, sdk

This app I completed around a year ago (!) but never launched it on the market place. I am trying to open it up in eclipse now to make some small modifications and work on the code a little bit. So I imported it and then found this weird "unable to resolve target" error. It's highlighting every class red in all my 'src' files.

I've looked at a similar question which said to add the line to default.properties file. My project has a project.properties file which has the line:

```
target=android-7
```

Any advice how to get this to work? I could always start a new project and just copy all the src files but that would be pretty lame and time-wasting.

One more comment - I'm developing on a new computer and I don't think I have the API level 7. Could that be the problem? I've gone into Window --> Android SDK Manager and the oldest available API it shows is level 8. But level 7 will mean I can target more devices I think so I'd like to go with that.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "I'm developing on a new computer and I don't think I have the API level 7"  If the manifest targets API 7 and you don't have API 7 installed, that would cause a few errors.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, yes that is your problem. You don't have the API level 7 downloaded. You can right click the project and go properties->android and select another available API. As long as you don't change the min sdk version in your manifest you are still targeting as many devices as before.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

**Update**

You don't have to do this, but you can get the older APIs on the [SDK Archives page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html)

I don't know if there is any official source for the next statement but that is what I found while working. If anybody can complete this with a better answer I would appreciate it very much.

You can compile the code with a newer SDK version as long as you don't use any code not compatible to the previous ones.

Example:

I want my app to be available for API level 7. But i only have API level 15 installed. As long as I keep the minSdkVersion="7" in my Manifest and don't use any resource not available in the previous APIs the app will work just fine on my targeted devices.

Comment: Ok so how would you recommend I get the API level 7? Because my SDK Manager doesn't list it as available for whatever reason.

Comment: @YoungMoney are you sure you have the latest SDK Manager? I have a recent install and it's listed there (it's Android 2.1). Perhaps you should reinstall your SDK Manager?

Comment: In order to use the facebook sdk, which requires min = "8", I had to install API 2.2 (SDK for 8)

Comment: @Austin you dont need to install Api 2.2 exactly. You can use 2.2 or any latter version.

Comment: @gameower you are correct. I did have to change my 'build target' from 2.3.3 to 2.2

Comment: @caiocpricci2 What I did is to set the Project Build Target to the latest one I have. Then I set the minSdkVersion to the oldest api version that is installed and set the targetSdkVersion to the latest one is installed.

Comment: Thank you so much i had same problem i am going to project > property > android and changed as you suggested an problem is solved

Comment: I couldn't find "right click->properties", seems like now it is "right click->open module settings (F4)", then it should open to the properties tab and you can select the SDK version there.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who wants to test their project against an API level that isn't the most recent one, you can just use the SDK Manager to install the old SDK:

In Eclipse (with adt installed):

[image]

SDK Manager:

[image]

Just check the box of the SDK you want to use to test against your project and click install. You can also remove API's that you aren't using.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project then:

**Properties -> Android -> Project build target -> Check Android 4.1.2**

Answer (score 1):

In your application's manifest.xml file add this tag

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

It's worked for me. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by editing my project.properties file
from: `target=android-7`
to: `target=android-19`.

I also changed the target sdk version in the manifest file:
`android:targetSdkVersion="19"`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I see the same problem when I import the android support v7 project as a library project in my own project,the eclipse says that cannot resolve android16, I find that it's the problem of the eclipse,you can right-click your project which has this problem,and then select properties,the Android pane,there is a Project Build Target pane there,you can see it easily,choose a standard android platform,like Android4.3,not others that start with Google API,I hope that this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

1. check android:minSdkVersion= in the AndroidManifest.xml
2. update target=android- in the project.properties if you use Eclipse IDE