# time picker with scroll for android?

Tags: android, android-layout, timepicker

I wish to have in my main view two scroll wheels for choosing time, one contains digits from 01-24, the other 00-60, with jumps of 5 (0,5,10..55)
Is there something ready for such a thing?
similar to http://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/, just android built-in.
The time picker is quite annoying..i need to press +- till i pick what i wish. i prefer something more touch-intuitive.
What options do i have exists for such a thing?

Comment: I have done something similar. But the list is not circular. Do you need the code?

Comment: I don't care if it's circular I just need something scrollable. Nothing to "expert". Meanwhile I will try the other suggestions

Comment: This works for my. It creates a snap-effect on the list view. If you need the xml, do let me know.

Comment: You can add your custom background to make things appear better.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing build in, but you could try this: 
http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

Comment: I tried to import the folder as android project and the error is: `[2013-02-22 15:27:42 - Main] Unable to resolve target 'android-3'
[2013-02-22 15:44:29 - wheel] Unable to resolve target 'android-7'
`

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find a complete project with source code.
[TestWheel.zip](http://www.filefactory.com/file/b3ge7hb/n/TestWheel.zip)

1. download the `TestWheel.zip` from the link.
2. Import it in your Eclipse
3. Convert this project into a library Project (rightclick on th testWheel project ==> properties ==> android ==> chek the `is library` check box).
4. Add this library project to your project.
5. copy and paste the following code in your XML file.

[image]

Comment: what errors you are getting now? i have implemented this even yesterday. its working good for me.

Comment: errors such as `[2013-02-22 15:27:42 - Main] Unable to resolve target 'android-3' [2013-02-22 15:44:29 - wheel] Unable to resolve target 'android-7' `

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278319/importing-project-gave-unable-to-resolve-target-android-7

Comment: set <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/> in your menifest file

Comment: and clean your project also

Answer (score 0):

Here's your hour_listView. Simply set a string adapter for it. Assuming that you can populate a listView using ArrayAdapter.

```
        hr_list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            int currentcount,topitem,firstitem,lastitem;
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && currentcount == 4) {
                    while (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    }

                    LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) view.getChildAt(0);
                    int height = item.getHeight();
                    int top = Math.abs(item.getTop()); // top is a negative value

                    if (top <= height/2){
                        view.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(topitem, 0, 3000);
                        Log.d("Switch", "up");
                    }
                    if(top> height/2){
                        view.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(topitem+1, 0,3000);
                        Log.d("Switch", "down");
                    }
                }
            }
```

And then set on a button.clickListener and you'll get the center row-number of the visible listView.

```
int list_hr = hr_list.getFirstVisiblePosition() - hr_list.getHeaderViewsCount();
```

Few key point.
* set divider height for listView 1dp.
*Use Linear layout to infalte in a listView
The row height should be 1/3 of the total listview heigth (in dp).

XML for listview and button

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Snap List"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="33dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:background="@drawable/lisbg"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
</ListView>

<StackView
    android:id="@+id/stackView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="103dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" >
</StackView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
    android:text="OK" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Scroll 5" />
```

XML for the row.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="TextView" />
```