# Unable to resolve target 'android-XX'

Tags: android

I am importing a project. It comes with errors in last activity file and these are the following entries in console:

```
[2013-04-04 12:00:59 - AndroidFragment] Unable to resolve target 'android-15'
[2013-04-04 12:10:31 - AndroidFragment] Unable to resolve target 'android-15'
```

I have fixed project setup and select the available target version by clicking on:

```
Project > Properties > Android > Project Build Target > Version
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: check you eclipse if you have that target installed

Comment: Can you see the Android 2.3.6 or something like in your project.?

Comment: `android-15` is for Android 4.0.3 version. In Eclipse goto Windows-> Preference->Android and check do you have that component, if not, then download it using Android SDK Manager and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Have you referred other questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942144/errorunable-to-resolve-target-android-2 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278319/importing-project-gave-unable-to-resolve-target-android-7

Comment: I was wondering raghu gave out the best answer here...

Answer (score 143, accepted):

1. Right click on your project.
2. Go to **Properties**.
3. Choose **Android** on the left side.
4. On the right, you can see a list of Android API versions. Choose the proper version (Android API 15).
5. Click **Apply**.

If you don't see the proper version, click on the **Window** menu, go to **Android SDK Manager** and download Android API 15 (Android 4.0.3). Repeat the steps above.

In the picture below, you can see API 16; not 15. You can download API 15 using Android SDK Manager. If you already have it, click the check box next to **Android 4.0.3**, click **Apply** and then **OK**.

[image]

To download an SDK from the SDK manager in Eclipse, click on the **Window** menu, **Android SDK Manager**. You should see the following window. Check **Android 4.0.3** which is API 15, and click **Install**.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, when I select the build target in here (it's downloaded and installed) and click apply, it does not save.

Comment: @K.Carpenter it will be downlaoded an i don't know what you mean by save

Comment: The problem was ADT ... when I changed the build target and clicked "Apply", it didn't actually apply (when I closed out and reopened the options, nothing was selected). I had to restart eclipse to get it to pick it up.

Comment: @Raghunandan. may I ask you to have a look at an android related question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968503/android-cannot-update-listview-on-changing-an-edittext-value ?

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan, your solution perfectly worked for me. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

## Update

#### 1. Open Sdk Manager from `Tools > Sdk Manager`

[image: screenshot sdkmanager 1]

[image: screenshot sdkmanager 2]

#### 2. Click on sdk which you want install, then click OK.

[image: screenshot sdkmanager 3]

Comment: I think the OP is using Eclipse, while your answer is in Android Studio.