# I found this type of error for first time

Tags: android

i am new to Android and i am trying to learn **webservices**.Recently i downloaded one source code for Webservices example.After i import that source i am getting following error and this is first time to see error like that.

```
Description                            Resource              Path   Location    Type

Unable to resolve target 'android-12'   WebserviceActivity           Unknown    Android Target Problem
```

Please help me to solve this error

Thanks

Comment: similar one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804261/unable-to-resolve-target-android-15/15804314#15804314

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Unable to resolve target 'android-##'" means that you have not downloaded to appropriate SDK for that API level. You need to open your SDK Manager and download the API that you need, in your case API 12.