# Unable to resolve target 'android-8' after importing libraries

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I've been struggling with importing an existing project to eclipse for a few days now and I've finally figured it out. I imported all the needed library projects and it works fine, but there's one more error.

Library project 'PortraitQR' has a red 'x' mark next to it says 'Unable to resolve target 'android-8''.

I tried to compile the application anyway but it crashes, here's the logcat file:

```
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{si.dvanadva.evanturist/si.dvanadva.evanturist.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "si.dvanadva.evanturist.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/si.dvanadva.evanturist-2.apk
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "si.dvanadva.evanturist.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/si.dvanadva.evanturist-2.apk
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
07-16 18:24:14.296: E/AndroidRuntime(9673):     ... 11 more
```

I did some research on how to fix android-8 resolve target error, but I can't find anywhere what to do if the error shows as soon as you import libraries. People usually have this error when updating with SDK manager.

Comment: Does your SDK manager show that Android API level 8 is installed?

Comment: What version of Android is your project set to compile to ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804261/unable-to-resolve-target-android-15/15804314#15804314. similar!.

Comment: @Tanis.7x thank you! I had to install API level 8

Comment: @Tanis.7x I have Android 4.4 API 19, but still doesn't work

Comment: @Nabin API versions are not cumulative- if your project uses API level 8, you need API level 8 installed, not 19.

Comment: @Tanis.7x Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381798/error-importing-facebook-sdk-for-facebook-sign-in-android/25381930?noredirect=1#comment39583495_25381930

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had to open up SDK manager and simply installed API level 8. That solved my problem. Vote up the user in the comments that gave me the solution :)

Answer (score 7):

in some cases after installation you should select the target platform for your project. to do so:

1. Right click on project->properties.
2. Select Android on left panel.
3. If you see Android 4.0.3 in (Project Build Target), then tick it and click Apply button.
4. If you don't have 4.0.3 version in Build Targets, then you don't have it yet. to install simply go to sdk manager and click on
   Android 4.0.3(API 15)-SDK Platform.