# Error importing Facebook SDK for Facebook Sign In Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

The document says

```
You'll need to have the Android 2.2 (API 8)
```

Can I only achieve it using **API 8**? I have been doing project on **API 14** and if I download API 8 and try to move forward, will I get trouble? What should I do?

**ERROR**

```
Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
```

I have consulted every question on StackOverFlow. But I'm not quite sure if to begin whole project with API 8 :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO. There is no trouble!! . Only **facebook sdk required to work mimimum API 8**, maximum they will update for new APIS's. That does not affect your project. You can choose any API's for your project.

See Below:

[image]

Comment: just make facebook sdk to android-8 that's it. SDK will require to work from min android-8.

Comment: as per says here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started. But working with android-14 have just checked.

Comment: Check. I have attached image.