# Error Message when Trying to Run the Sample Cocos-2DX Android Project on Eclipse

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

After following the directions on the Cocos-2DX site to [get the android environment set up](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_set_up_the_android_cocos2d-x_development_environment_on_Windows_7), I'm coming across this issue when trying the run the project as an Android application

> [2013-12-03 22:12:10 - HelloCpp] Unable to resolve target 'android-13'
>   [2013-12-03 22:21:10 - HelloCpp]     (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
>   [2013-12-03 22:21:10 - HelloCpp]       Unable to add 'D:\Cocos-2DX\cocos2d-x-2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\assets\app.icf': Zip add failed
>   [2013-12-03 22:21:10 - HelloCpp] ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging 'D:\Cocos-2DX\cocos2d-x-2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_'
>   [2013-12-03 22:21:10 - HelloCpp] ERROR: packaging of 'D:\Cocos-2DX\cocos2d-x-2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_' failed

All my path and environment variables have been set up, so I'm not sure what could be causing the issue. Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Right click project --> go to properties --> select Android from there --> and from the list of target name select Android 3.2 or lesser

Error means that you do not have api level 13 installed in your sdk manager. So you can download api 13 using android sdk manager.

Also check this : [SO Post for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804261/unable-to-resolve-target-android-15)

Hope this helps.

Comment: [2013-12-04 19:04:19 - HelloCpp] (skipping file '.gitignore' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[2013-12-04 19:04:19 - HelloCpp] Unable to add 'D:\Cocos-2DX\cocos2d-x-2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\assets\app.icf': Zip add failed
[2013-12-04 19:04:19 - HelloCpp] ERROR: unable to process assets while packaging 'D:\Cocos-2DX\cocos2d-x-2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_'
[2013-12-04 19:04:19 - HelloCpp] ERROR: packaging of 'D:\Cocos-2DX\cocos2d-x-2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android\bin\resources.ap_' failed

Comment: any solution to this? I am experiencing the same issue and cannot find any help

Comment: Clean the project and try to run again.