# Logcat and project not showing any error

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-support-library

I am adding support library to my project. I have added `android-support-v7-appcompat`.But when I added that in my project Its showing `Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list appcompat in android` error then I deleted `android-support-v4` and add library in my project. Now I dont having any errors in my code. But when I try to run my project its showing some errors in project. But not showing in logcat or package explorer. Why this happen?

Comment: There were two versions of the support library in your workspace, use the same one everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the support library from

```
android-sdk/extras/android/support/v4-android-support-v4.jar
```

and add it to libs folder of `AppCompat` and android project. Make sure you have updated support library. Remove the old ones. Clean and build the project.

Comment: when i run my project its show android library projects cannot be launched.

Comment: @JohnR remove it and copy the latest one to the libs folder. THe version that your project has and the appcompat has do not match. makes sure you have the same version for both

Comment: I have done exactly same as you suggest in your answer but when i run my project its show android library projects cannot be launched.

Comment: @JohnR you need to launch your android project. not your library project. makes sense!. read about it in the docs

Comment: @JohnR read this. all there in the docs http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: I am running my project not AppCompat.

Comment: seems you made your project a library project then. right click on your project. goto properties android.  see if is library is checked. If so uncheck for your project.

Comment: I am following links in this link. http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46412/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-john-r)

Comment: @JohnR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804261/unable-to-resolve-target-android-15/15804314#15804314. pls post a new question for a new problem