# No resource found - Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I used ActionBar Style Generator, and now trying to use into my app, but getting :

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/
>        Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

i am using **android-support-v7-appcompat.jar** lib inside libs folder

my target is to make my app compatible 2.3 or above

Comment: did you add the jar to libs folder?

Comment: yes android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

Comment: @AbrahimNeil : see [Can't Find Theme.AppCompat.Light for New Android ActionBar Support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support) maybe help you

Answer (score 101, accepted):

`AppCompat` is a library project. You need to reference the library project in your android project.

Check the topic [**Adding libraries with resources**](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library).

**Update**

Adding material theme should be the way. Check https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started for more details.

Comment: already placed android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to libs folder

Comment: @AbrahimNeil that is not the right way. its a library project and hence must be referenced just like google play services

Comment: when i am importing android-support-v7-appcompat.jar getting Unable to resolve target android-16 is it requires ?

Comment: @AbrahimNeil follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804261/unable-to-resolve-target-android-15 assuming you are using eclipse ide

Comment: i ticked as useful both this and that, my only concern was is it requires ?

Comment: you can check it to 17 if you have or download 16 if you want to.

Comment: i am just using android 19 :( this even without Google APIs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47919/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-abrahim-neil)

Comment: adding     `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`,
under dependencies solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, Hilal, adding that in the project's Gradle file worked for me.

Comment: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'` for androidx

Answer (score 34):

If you're using **Eclipse**, then add the `reference library` into your project as the following steps:

1. Right-click your project in the `Project Explorer` View.
2. Click `Properties`.
3. Click `Android` in the `Properties` window.
4. In the `Library` group, click `Add...`

   - See the image below.
5. Select the library. **Click** `OK`.
6. Click the `OK` button again in the Properties window.

[image: The "Add" button in the project Properties window, Android section, Library group.]

Comment: how do you know op is using eclipse not android studio?. the snap posted is for eclipse.

Comment: @Raghunandan sorry forget to mention it

Comment: Works perfectly in Eclipse. Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

If you are using **Android Studio** then just add the dependency

```
dependencies {
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
}
```

to `app/build.gradle`. And that will work

Comment: Um... it *doesn't* work... it still won't resolve android:Theme.AppCompat.* in my styles.xml file.

Comment: I just replaced implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' by implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1' and now it works... but why?

Comment: @CGR I believe Android changed the themes for 28+ and Light.DarkActionBar isn't available anymore.

Answer (score 14):

For anyone out there using VS2015, I was getting this error too, and it turns out I hadn't added the library to the project...

```
Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
```

Comment: I got this after starting a fresh project in VS2019 and Building it.  Simply doing a "Rebuild Solution" without having to install anything else resolved the errors.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Eclipse just copying android-support-v7-appcompat.jar to libs folder will not work if you are going to use resources.

Follow steps from here for "[Adding libraries with resources](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library)".

Answer (score 8):

A simple solution - replace contents this file (/res/values/styles.xml) to this is text:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: "Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'AppBaseTheme'."

Comment: This is not **AppCompat**.

Answer (score 5):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

compile has been replaced by implementation, don't know why.

Comment: This is the solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I took an `android` project from one computer to another and had this problem.  What worked for me was a combination of some of the answers I've seen:

- Remove the copy of the appcompat library that was in the libs folder
  of the workspace
- Install sdk 21
- Change the project properties to use that sdk build
  [image]
- Set up and start an emulator compatible with sdks 21
- Update the Run Configuration to prompt for device to run on & choose
  Run

Mine ran fine after these steps.

Answer (score 4):

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

}
```

This worked for me... in Android Studio...

Answer (score 3):

Using Visual Studio 2015 (Windows7) + Xamarin had this error and after trying multiple things (installing packages, download android_m2repository_r10.zip...) ended removing the full **Xamarin folder** inside

> ```
> C:\Users\<my user>\AppData\Local
> ```

After that, Rebuild the application in VS and errors disappeared.

Comment: This worked for me :)
 Note: Using Visual Studio Enterprise. 2017 15.8 Preview 3.0

Comment: Worked for me as well, using VS 2017.

Answer (score 3):

make sure there is a v7 directory in your sdk, I thought having the 'Android Support Library' (in Extras) was sufficient. Turns out I was missing the 'Local Maven repository for Support Libraries (extras;android;m2repository)' Studio found that actually and fixed  the gradle dependencies. using gradle to build then worked.
$ cat app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pat.example.com.gdbdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Android.mk to build then use the USE_AAPT2, which link in the built resource from the AAR.

Add below line in Android.mk file:

LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your SDK in the manager and be sure to include `Android
   support library` in extra's
2. Go to SDK in file explorer (Finder on mac) track down the extra's
   folder (`..\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values` on
   Windows). Somewhere in there is a `themes.xml` and
   `themes_base.xml`. Copy both of these files.
3. In your project paste the files into 'values' directory

Comment: Copying themes_base.xml into res/values solved the original problem but resulted in other unresolved references.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse: When importing a support library as a project library following the instructions at [Adding Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library), **don't forget to check the option "Copy proyects into workspace"**!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. None of the solutions listed here helped my situation. As it turns out, I was importing the parent folder for a project into Android Studio 1.5, rather than the project folder itself. This threw Gradel into a tizzy. Solution was to import the project folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Visual Studio for MAC**, fix the problem clicking on Project > Restoring Nutget packages

Answer (score -1):

In xamarin if you face this issue when you add any new sdk.
The simple solution is Open your styles file and add
this line.

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>`

It's better solution rather than adding appcompat.

Comment: This would mean that your app would be using the old Android styling, instead of Material Design.