# No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I am using Android Studio **(non gradle project)**, so no previous answers have been helpful to me.

In my styles.xml I am getting the error from the title on

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

[image]

Comment: is it in your styles folder?

Comment: do you have a folder called appcompat_v7?

Comment: @Clay I con't have a styles folder. I have a values folder that has a styles.xml

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin no I don't have an appcompat_v7 folder. Do I need one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900853/no-resource-found-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar Take a look at this, you need to reference the appcombat library in your project

Comment: @AdamJohns then you just solve your problem.. that theme is from appcompat folder, and yes you need that folder..

Comment: I have a folder called 'android-support-v7-appcompat'. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @AdamJohns what is in your libs folder of your project??

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin updated with libs folder photo

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html Go to **Adding libraries with resources** and follow that

Comment: @Clay this is not a gradle project.

Comment: lol didnt see android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had several 3rd party libraries contained in my project. When I selected each of them and imported them as a module, the style error went away.

File > Project Structure > Modules > click + > import module > add each project folder as module

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to copy the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` of your `android-support-v7-appcompat` from the libs folder of it, into your project folder libs.

After Right click on your `project`, select `Build Path` -> `Configure build path`.

Select `Library Tab` then `Add Jar` option and browse your `android-support-v7-appcompat` and click OK.

Lastly clean and build.

Comment: I don't have an option for Build path when I right click my project. It is not a gradle project.

Comment: @AdamJohns go properties instead of Build path

Comment: there is no properties if I right click my project.

Comment: @AdamJohns I never work in android studio but you can check this out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk