# Error in Eclipse before I've written my first line of code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I downloaded Eclipse and all the accompanying plugins according to my University's instruction page, which were given [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).  Hopefully you're familiar with them.

I then opened Eclipse and tried to start my first project, when I'm getting this error in one window

parseSdkContent failed

Android SDK Content Loader

Android SDK Content Loader

And these errors showing on the console:

```
[2014-12-06 13:23:19 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\MyName\workspace\MyFirstApp\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-12-06 13:23:19 - MyFirstApp] 
[2014-12-06 13:23:33 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\MyName\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-12-06 13:23:33 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\MyName\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
```

So it's a problem with the SDK?  Am I just missing a specific file?  This is just after I open Eclipse and create a new project.  I haven't written a single line of code yet.  Thanks for any help, guys.

Comment: Possible duplicate, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900853/no-resource-found-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar

Comment: I followed the instructions in that thread up to step 3.  I'm trying to Browse the sdk folder, the only folders I can click are the avd and cache folders, and I can't expand them to find more files.  Am I even looking in the right spot?