# when i start a new android project, it gives me 3 "styles.xml" error

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

i'm new to coding  when i start android in java it gives me this three error, how can i fix it ? i used java EE eclipse.

- workspace\test\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving
  parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
  'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
- workspace\test\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving
  parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
  'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
- workspace\test\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving
  parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
  'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: Hope to help you : http://stackoverflow.com/q/21900853/4002393

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project and build again