# Unit test for android studio will not start because the styles.xml file cannot find the "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Tags: android, xml, unit-testing

I am trying to test the database using an AndroidJUnit4 test and the test keeps failing. 
I have tried commenting it out but it still will not work.

This is the error I get:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\Bennett\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1

It also says for the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`:
cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No resource found - Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900853/no-resource-found-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppCompat` is a library. You need to reference the library in your android project.

Check this link and follow it: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library

You need to download Android Support Library and Repository from your SDK Manager.