# Location control is disabled in emulator controls

Tags: android, location, controls

I am trying to hit the send button in location control under manual in emulator controls, but then I realized that it is disabled.
I am trying out a location app and I require it to be enabled.
Can you please suggest me a good solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource found - Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900853/no-resource-found-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar)

Comment: *Why dont i get a home screen?* - Because your app can't build. There's a lot of duplicate questions with that exact error message

Answer (score 0):

This theme is shipped with AppCompat support library, so make sure you have added the following dependency to your module's dependencies.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use below code in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```