# Errors when starting a new android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I start a new Android project in Eclipse. I get the following errors

> No resource found that matches the given name 'theme.appcompact.light.darkactionbar';
>
> No resource found that matches the given name 
>   'theme.appcompact.light';
>
> No resource found that matches the given name 
>   '(at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher')

I don't change the code or anything but these errors appear.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing AppCompat library reference. Check this other question for your first two problems: [No resource found - Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900853/no-resource-found-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar)

For the missing ic_launcher, you need to have an icon on your drawable folder. Put any PNG file with the name ic_launcher in your drawable folder and error should be gone. But been this a freshly started new project, maybe you removed it by accident?