# Why does AppTheme style .Parent need "Base.Theme..."

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles

I had an error

> Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error in android studio

and the solution was simple:

change

```
< style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<   style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I am not clear why this change was made. Please can anyone provide me with the reason?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17870881/1531971 https://stackoverflow.com/q/21900853/1531971 (etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with how some versions of Android Studio handle some `appcompat` support library versions. You can find a more detailed answer here:

[Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449275/failed-to-load-appcompat-actionbar-with-unknown-error-in-android-studio)

After updating AS to 3.2 and Gradle to 4.6, the problem is gone for me.