# Error: "resource style/Base.Theme not found" in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-theme

I keep receiving this error `resource style/Base.Theme not found` while compiling and I do not understand what's wrong.

I also receive

> missing resource errors: "Base.ThemeOverlay", "Base.V11.Theme"

Should I define such a `Base.Theme` resource? Should I include some libraries?

I made a lot of research and read the documentation, but it looks like that things get very different from version to version (I'm using targetSdk=21).

I looked here: [No resource found - Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900853/no-resource-found-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar)

And here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

and here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#using-apis

and here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/49aa2c906743522399645cb394dadec91f9ad99c/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And add theme and error in question.

Comment: Thank you @ADM for your answer. The error is the one in the title, I modified the question to make it more clear.
May you please tell me how to understand what theme am I using? I do not even understand that.

Comment: Add style.xml in question . Or use `Theme.AppCompat` .  [Here](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/example-usage-of-appcompatactivity-in-android/) is an old tutorial . try  to find new one .

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to your project directory (or to `Project View`)
2. Find and open `.idea` directory
3. Remove `caches` and `libraries` directories   <-- this is essential
4. `Invalidate Caches / Restart`