# Cannot Successfully Create An Android Application Project In Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am attempting to create a project, in eclipse IDE using android extensions, but i always receive this error when creating the project:

```
[2018-08-02 01:56:28 - kk] C:\Users\Joshua\eclipse-workspace\kk\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2018-08-02 01:56:28 - kk] 
[2018-08-02 01:56:28 - kk] C:\Users\Joshua\eclipse-workspace\kk\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2018-08-02 01:56:28 - kk] 
[2018-08-02 01:56:28 - kk] C:\Users\Joshua\eclipse-workspace\kk\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2018-08-02 01:56:28 - kk] 
[2018-08-02 01:56:30 - kk] C:\Users\Joshua\eclipse-workspace\kk\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2018-08-02 01:56:30 - kk] 
[2018-08-02 01:56:30 - kk] C:\Users\Joshua\eclipse-workspace\kk\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2018-08-02 01:56:30 - kk] 
[2018-08-02 01:56:30 - kk] C:\Users\Joshua\eclipse-workspace\kk\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2018-08-02 01:56:30 - kk] 
[2018-08-02 01:56:32 - kk] C:\Users\Joshua\eclipse-workspace\kk\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2018-08-02 01:56:32 - kk] 
[2018-08-02 01:56:32 - kk] C:\Users\Joshua\eclipse-workspace\kk\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2018-08-02 01:56:32 - kk] 
[2018-08-02 01:56:32 - kk] C:\Users\Joshua\eclipse-workspace\kk\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

I have installed everything correctly and i am using the most updated versions, including the SDKs. If you have any insight into what might be going wrong please let me know as it will be a huge help.

Thanks is advance!!

Comment: check this link please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900853/no-resource-found-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No resource found - Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900853/no-resource-found-theme-appcompat-light-darkactionbar)