# Compilation error while importing a project into a workspace

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting the following error in eclipse when importing a project.

Please help me on this issue; how would I resolve it?

```
[2014-03-07 16:37:39 - Dex Loader] SecurityException: Unable to find field for dex.jar
[2014-03-07 16:38:17 - FSTPSplashActivity] Unable to resolve target 'android-17'
[2014-03-07 16:38:18 - RuleEng] Unable to resolve target 'android-17'
[2014-03-07 16:38:19 - FSTPSplashActivity] Unable to resolve target 'android-17'
[2014-03-07 16:38:19 - FSTPSplashActivity] Unable to resolve target 'android-17'
[2014-03-07 16:38:19 - FSTPSplashActivity] Unable to resolve target 'android-
```

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804261/unable-to-resolve-target-android-15/15804314#15804314

Comment: open your sdk manager and see the latest version of android installed and go to project.properties and edit there

Answer (score 1):

```
Unable to resolve target 'android-17'
```

open the `Android SDK Manager` and install it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error Because target 17 that is `Android 4.2.2(API 17)` is not installed in your system.

There might be 2 possibility either you open the Android SDK Manager and install it. or right click on your project then go to **properties**, select the **Android** option and change the version of android which you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

check your `project.properties` how much android version is written there... surely be 17, reduce it to whatever you have installed, if your maximum android api is 16 and in properties if it is 17 then in that case this error comes
then in place of `android-17` change it to something like `android-16` or whatever version you are having installed in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

**There must be the Google API level 17 Android 4.2.2(API 17) installed in your SDK.**

[image]

Make sure you are trying to run your project using the `Google API Emulator` and your project API is also having the API level of `Google API` version.