# Getting my old version of Eclipse SDK Version: 3.6.2 up and running again?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I have written a number of simple apps for Android, but have not posted any on Android Market / Google Play for about a year or two.  I recently wrote a very simple app but when I tried to post it to Google Play I get the Error:

`You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned.  You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.`

Google must have changed something while I was napping.
After a little research I found that I needed to load the latest version of Eclipse as the Export/Signing tool included in the newer versions also does this zip aligning.
This was a mistake I think.

First I tried to get the update function on the Eclipse SDK Version: 3.6.2 I had been using but this did not work.  In frustration I simply loaded the latest version of the SDK off the Android site.  This worked fine but the Emulator that comes with it is far too slow on my computer (MacBook Pro OS 10.6.8, 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 2 GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM).  I tried a number of suggestions on getting a faster Emulator, none of which worked.

Since the emulator on my 3.6.2 version of Eclipse worked just fine for the simple apps I write I said well I will just use that version of Eclipse and zip align my app manually.  Unfortunately, now ALL my apps on the older version of Eclipse have errors in them preventing them from working.  I keep on getting the error:

```
[2014-05-18 22:53:56 - Focal Length] Unable to resolve target 'android-19'
```

This is understandable as I only have API 17 installed on this older version of Eclipse (that is as high as I could load on this version).  I thought, fine I will just uninstall the latest version of Eclipse then the old one will work fine.  No luck, when I uninstall the latest version of Eclipse and even use an app cleaner on my Mac I still get the same error:

```
[2014-05-18 22:53:56 - Focal Length] Unable to resolve target 'android-19'
```

Somewhere in my old Eclipse there is a pointer asking for API 19 which does not exist on my old version of Eclipse.

I would like to simply use my old version of Eclipse and zip align my app manually as outlined in on the Android site.

Can someone help me in getting my old version of Eclipse SDK Version: 3.6.2 up and running again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804261/unable-to-resolve-target-android-15

Answer (score 0):

either change your android target to lower version. or open up android sdk manger and install android 4.4.2 sdk.

Comment: Thanks, changed target to lower version, API 8 in this case.  Solved some of the errors but still get an "R cannot be resolved to a 
 variable" error in the following code:    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: either your resources are not compiled or you are missing import to the R class. try a clean build

Answer (score 0):

Never found solution, tried everything, numerous suggestions from stack overflow.  I could never get my apps to work on my old version of Eclipse no matter what.  New version of Eclipse still too slow of Emulator.  Tried running apps directly off my phone, Samsung Galaxy S3 but could not ever get Eclipse to recognize it.  Tried loading and running Samsung Kies no help.  Only way I could modify app was to open it on latest version of eclipse, run it, kill the run, and then email the apk file to my phone.  This worked but the text was then all off.  Tried to correct that also and now the new version of Eclipse has nothing but errors in it.

Final solution?  Back up my Workspace files and uninstall all versions of Eclipse on my Mac along with any remnants I can find.

I will then reload the latest version of Eclipse and manually enter the code in for my app and see if that works.

Just a work of experience from an 54 year old chemical engineer that has designed almost any type of chemical plant there is (and used punch cards in college!).  Even though most chemical plants are computer controlled there is always a manual OFF switch so that operators at 3 AM in the morning can shut things down safely without having to look for the "bug" in the program.